# BiBTeX + amsalpha + incollection + NOTE = strange result

Tags: bibtex

I'm using amsalpha as the bibliography style and abusing the NOTE field to link to arXiv and DOI. (Yes, I know that's a hack, but I can't help it. :| ) Ususally, this works fine; e. g., the entry

```
@article {FGKS,
AUTHOR = {Arthur {Fischer} and Martin {Goldstern} and Jakob {Kellner} and Saharon {Shelah}},
TITLE = {{Creature Forcing and Five Cardinal Characteristics in {Cicho{\'n}'s} Diagram}},
JOURNAL = {Arch. Math. Logic},
FJOURNAL = {Archive for Mathematical Logic},
VOLUME = {56},
YEAR = {2017},
NUMBER = {7--8},
PAGES = {1045--1103},
ISSN = {0933-5846},
CODEN = {AMLOEH},
NOTE = {\href{https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00153-017-0553-8}{\textsc{doi}:~10.1007/S00153-017-0553-8}, \href{https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0367}{arXiv:~1402.0367 [math.LO]}},
URL = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0367},
}
```

is output as

[FGKS17] Arthur Fischer, Martin Goldstern, Jakob Kellner, and Saharon Shelah, *Creature Forcing and Five Cardinal Characteristics in Cichoń’s Diagram*, Arch. Math. Logic **56** (2017), no. 7–8, 1045–1103, [DOI: 10.1007/S00153-017-0553-8](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00153-017-0553-8), [arXiv: 1402.0367 [math.LO]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0367).

My problem is that @incollection entries are formatted incorrectly. For example,

```
@incollection {Blass93,
AUTHOR = {Andreas {Blass}},
TITLE = {{Simple Cardinal Characteristics of the Continuum}},
BOOKTITLE = {{S}et {T}heory of the {R}eals},
EDITOR = {Haim {Judah}},
PAGES = {63--90},
SERIES = {Israel Mathematics Conference Proceedings},
VOLUME = {6},
PUBLISHER = {Gelbart Research Institute for Mathematical Sciences, Bar-Ilan University, Ramat-Gan},
YEAR = {1993},
NOTE = {\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/9405202}{arXiv:~9405202 [math.LO]}},
URL = {http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/sccc.pdf},
}
```

is output as

[Bla93] Andreas Blass, *Simple Cardinal Characteristics of the Continuum*, Set Theory of the Reals (Haim Judah, ed.), Israel Mathematics Conference Proceedings, vol. 6, Gelbart Research Institute for Mathematical Sciences, Bar-Ilan University, Ramat-Gan, 1993, [arXiv: 9405202 [math.LO]](http://arxiv.org/abs/9405202), pp. 63–90.

… with the pages *after* the note.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this expected behaviour (and if so, why)? Is there a reasonably easy way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Off-topic: Why are the surnames of all authors and editors encased in curly braces? This shouldn't be necessary at all.

Comment: Why do you believe that it's wrong for the information from the `pages` field to be placed last for entries of type `@incollection`? Looking at the code contained in `amsalpha.bst`, I'd say that this outcome is exactly what this bibliography style is supposed to do.

Comment: Surnames: TBH, I copied that technique from someone without asking. My best guess: Some people have surnames consisting of more than one word, and for those, it helps with inverting surnames and first names?

Pages last: Because it seems entirely nonsensical to me to have the pages be the last entry, especially *after* notes and the likes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code in the file `amsalpha.bst` that formats entries of type `@incollection`:

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.incoll.title.editors "booktitle" output.check
      format.bookvolume.series.number output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  note output
  format.book.pages output
  format.language *
  fin.entry
}
```

Without going into too many details, do observe that the `pages` field is set to be output *after*, not before, the `note` field.

You asked,

> ... with the pages after the note. ... Is this expected behaviour (and if so, why)?

Yes, this is the expected behavior. I'm afraid I'm in no position to address your *why* question.

You also asked,

> Is there a reasonably easy way to change this behaviour?

Find the file `amsalpha.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `myamsalpha.bst`. (Don't edit an original, unrenamed file from the TeX distribution.) Open the file `myamsalpha.bst` in a text editor and locate the function `incollection`. (It should look like the code shown above.) Interchange the order of the lines

```
      note output
      format.book.pages output
```

so that they look like this:

```
      format.book.pages output
      note output
```

Save the file `myamsalpha.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}` to `\bibliographystyle{myamsalpha}` and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

A final comment: I assume that you're using the `amsalpha` bib style because you have to do so. If that's the case, it's almost certainly a poor idea to modify the bib style.

Comment: (I'm using the amsalpha style because it mostly does what I want it to do for my preprints and my thesis, except for @incollection. ;) I know that journals will do their own thing, anyway. Thanks a lot!)

Comment: @LukasDanielKlausner - You're most welcome! :-)